# Copy a variable by separating it from it

Tags: python, python-3.7

yesterday I asked a question about a problem I was having: [Create Entities Reduce FPS And Overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254239/create-entities-reduce-fps-and-overlapping). I managed to solve the problem of the decline in FPS with this logic:

1. I create a model for each type of entity.
2. When I create a new entity, I simply copy the model data.

As a result, the entity creation function has been reduced to this:

```
def create_entity(self, pos_x, pos_y, obj):
    if obj not in self.main.model.model_enemy:
        entity = self.main.model.model_enemy["0000"]
    else:
        entity = self.main.model.model_enemy[obj]
    entity["battle"]["position"] = (pos_x, pos_y)
    entity["battle"]["sprite"][entity["battle"]["state"]][entity["battle"]["direction"]].x = pos_x
    entity["battle"]["sprite"][entity["battle"]["state"]][entity["battle"]["direction"]].y = pos_y
    return entity
```

The function is called, giving it the parameters: `pos_x`, `pos_y` (the position in which the entity will be drawn) and `obj` (the model chosen for the entity). The `if` statement checks if the requested template is present in `self.main.model.model_enemy` (it contains all the models). If it is not present, it assigns it the basic model. The next part is simple setting of the position. When finished, the created entity will be returned.

The problem I'm having is that if I edit an attribute of any entity created this way (each entity when created is placed in a list), I edit it for all entities.

This happens, I think, because when I assign the model type to the entity (`entity = self.main.model.model_enemy`), I do not actually make a copy of the model. So, going to change an attribute of an entity, I'm actually going to change that of the model. As a result, all entities created with that model are modified. What I need instead is to copy the model, so that it remains separate from it. In this way I can modify the attributes of the entities, without modifying the model itself.

I've already tried with: `copy.deepcopy`, but it does not work, since it gives me error. What can you advise me? The problem I'm having is for Python, that's why there is no Pyglet tag.

I leave you a basic model, so that you can see how it is composed (the model still lacks the parts that I must add in the future):

```
OrderedDict([('battle', OrderedDict([('tile', 24), ('image', OrderedDict([('idle', OrderedDict([(0, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (1, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (2, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (3, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (4, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>)])), ('movement', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C2160>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C26A0>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C2C18>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9467CF60>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C57F0>)])), ('attack', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C5D68>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947CA320>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947CA898>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947CAE10>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF952503C8>)])), ('sp_attack_1', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF952506A0>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95250AC8>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF952570B8>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF952574A8>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF952578D0>)])), ('sp_attack_2', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95257DD8>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525A208>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525A588>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525A9B0>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525AF60>)])), ('hurt', OrderedDict([(0, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (1, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (2, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (3, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>), (4, <ImageDataRegion 24x24>)])), ('asleep', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95261B38>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95267080>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF952674A8>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95267A20>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95267F28>)]))])), ('texture', OrderedDict([('idle', OrderedDict([(0, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (1, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (2, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (3, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (4, <TextureRegion 48x48>)])), ('movement', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C2128>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C24E0>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C2A58>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C5128>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C5630>)])), ('attack', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C5BA8>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947CA160>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947CA6D8>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947CAC50>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95250208>)])), ('sp_attack_1', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95250940>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95250D68>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95257320>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95257748>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95257B70>)])), ('sp_attack_2', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF947C5470>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525A400>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525A828>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9525AC50>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95261160>)])), ('hurt', OrderedDict([(0, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (1, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (2, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (3, <TextureRegion 48x48>), (4, <TextureRegion 48x48>)])), ('asleep', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95261EB8>), (1, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95267320>), (2, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95267748>), (3, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF95267C88>), (4, <pyglet.image.Animation object at 0x000002BF9526D160>)]))])), ('sprite', OrderedDict([('idle', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF8884FD30>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947B76D8>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947B7780>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947B7828>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947B7A20>)])), ('movement', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947C20B8>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947C2550>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947C2AC8>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947C50B8>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947C56A0>)])), ('attack', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947C5C18>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947CA1D0>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947CA748>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF947CACC0>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95250278>)])), ('sp_attack_1', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952507F0>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95250C18>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952571D0>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952575F8>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95257A20>)])), ('sp_attack_2', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95257E80>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF9525A2B0>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF9525A6D8>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF9525AB00>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952610B8>)])), ('hurt', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952612E8>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95261390>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95261588>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95261780>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95261978>)])), ('asleep', OrderedDict([(0, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95261D68>), (1, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952671D0>), (2, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF952675F8>), (3, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF95267B38>), (4, <pyglet.sprite.Sprite object at 0x000002BF9526D0B8>)]))])), ('state', 'idle'), ('direction', 0), ('position', (0, 0))]))])
```

EDIT:
This is the error I get with `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/Project/PE/Project.py", line 479, in <module>
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 138, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 142, in run
    self._run()
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 154, in _run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 275, in idle
    redraw_all = self.clock.call_scheduled_functions(dt)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\clock.py", line 346, in call_scheduled_functions
    item.func(now - item.last_ts, *item.args, **item.kwargs)
  File "F:/Python/Project/PE/Project.py", line 142, in update
    up()
  File "F:/Python/Project/PE/Project.py", line 256, in update
    entity = self.create_entity(x, y, "0001")
  File "F:/Python/Project/PE/Project.py", line 238, in create_entity
    entity = copy.deepcopy(self.main.model.model_enemy["0000"])
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
    value = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
    value = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
    value = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
    value = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "F:\Python\Python37\lib\copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

Comment: Why not tell us what error `deepcopy` gives, and how you are trying to use it? It sounds as if that ought to work, so you must be doing something wrong there.

Comment: Show the code that's getting the error from `deepcopy()`, and post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: @usr2564301 Excuse me, you're right. I added the error.

Comment: @Barmar Excuse me, you're right. I added the error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768218/how-to-save-ctypes-objects-containing-pointers

Comment: @Barmar I read, but I did not understand much.

Comment: The problem is that you have `ImageDataRegion` objects in your dictionary, and `deepcopy` doesn't know how to copy them. So you need to write your own recursive copy function that does the right thing with these objects.

Comment: @Barmar Ah... Would you have advice to give me on how I should do the function?

Comment: Write a recursive function that copies your data. When it gets to the `ImageDataRegion` objects it can probably just assign them directly, it might not need to make copies of them. But I don't really know what these are so I can't be sure.